# Functional Purity using 'let' in Haskell

Tags: haskell

As I am working on learning Haskell, I understand it is a purely functional language. I am having trouble understanding why `let`-statements don't violate purity.

For example (in ghci):

```
Prelude> let e = exp 1
Prelude> e
2.718281828459045
Prelude> let e = 2
Prelude> e
2
```

isn't my second `let` statement producing a side effect? Or is the second `let` statement a new closure?

Comment: @jberryman 2) and 3) were already covered in the second half of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545580/functional-purity-using-let-in-haskell/13545731#13545731) following dbaupp's similar comment below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your second `let` creates a new binding for `e` that shadows the existing variable. It does not modify `e`. You can easily check this with the following:

```
Prelude> let e = 1
Prelude> let f () = "e is now " ++ show e
Prelude> f ()
"e is now 1"
Prelude> let e = 2
Prelude> e
2
Prelude> f ()
"e is now 1"
Prelude>
```

Answer (score 17):

`let` introduces a new local variable with a single unalterable value, and it has more local scope than any surrounding definitions, so for example:

```
*Main> (let length = 2 in show length) ++ ' ':show (length "Hello")
"2 5"
```

Here the first `length` has the value 2, but its scope local to the brackets. Outside the brackets, `length` means what it has always meant. Nothing has been edited, just a more local variable has been introduced that happens to have the same name as another one in a different scope. Let's make ghci mad by omitting the brackets and making it try to make `length` a number and a function:

```
*Main> let length = 2 in show length ++ ' ':show (length "Hello")

<interactive>:1:14:
    No instance for (Num ([Char] -> a0))
      arising from the literal `2'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num ([Char] -> a0))
    In the expression: 2
    In an equation for `length': length = 2
    In the expression:
      let length = 2 in show length ++ ' ' : show (length "Hello")

<interactive>:1:19:
    No instance for (Show ([Char] -> a0))

      arising from a use of `show'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show ([Char] -> a0))
    In the first argument of `(++)', namely `show length'
    In the expression: show length ++ ' ' : show (length "Hello")
    In the expression:
      let length = 2 in show length ++ ' ' : show (length "Hello")
```

And here's your example:

```
*Main> let e = exp 1 in show e ++ " " ++ let e = 2 in show e
"2.718281828459045 2"
```

I'll add brackets to emphasise the scope:

```
*Main> let e = exp 1 in (show e ++ " " ++ (let e = 2 in (show e)))
"2.718281828459045 2"
```

The first `e` is hidden rather than edited. Referential transparency is preserved, but it's definitely bad practice because it's hard to follow.

---

Now secretly the interactive prompt is a bit like one big `do` block in the IO monad, so let's look at that:

```
testdo = do
  let e = exp 1
  print e
  let e = 2
  print e
```

Now I have to admit that looks an awful lot like breaking referential transparency, but bear in mind that this looks like it does too:

```
testWrite = do
   writeFile "test.txt" "Hello Mum"
   xs <- readFile "test.txt"
   print xs
   writeFile "test.txt" "Yo all"
   xs <- readFile "test.txt"
   print xs
```

Now in what sense have we got referential transparency? `xs` clearly refers to two different strings. Well, what does this `do` notation actually mean? It's syntactic sugar for

```
testWrite = writeFile "test.txt" "Hello Mum"
         >> readFile "test.txt" 
         >>= (\xs -> print xs 
         >> writeFile "test.txt" "Yo all"
         >> readFile "test.txt"
         >>= (\xs -> print xs))
```

Now it's clearer that what looks like assignment is just local scope again. You presumably are happy to do

```
increment :: [Int] -> [Int]
increment = \x -> map (\x -> x+1) x
```

Which is doing the same thing.

---

**Summary**
What appeared to be assignment is just introduction of a new local scope. Phew. If you use this a lot, you make it very unclear what your code means.

Comment: Note that the question uses `let` in a do-notation context i.e. `do { ...; let e = 1; ... }` rather than in a `let ... in ...` context. The reasoning is pretty much identical, but it's worth mentioning.